# Mesh will not move with rig

Tags: mesh, rigging

I am on 3.0.  I just created a rig for a human mesh.  When I move the any part of the rig the only thing that moves is the rig.  Its like the mesh wasnt joined with the rig when the rig was created.  Any idea how I can get the mesh and rig to be symbiotic?  I have watched to many videos but they seem to focus on only on part of the mesh having the issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you parent the mesh to the rig?  If so, how did you?

Comment: In object mode I selected "rig"  then edit mode I selected the mesh.  CTRL + P and selected Connected.

Comment: don't change to edit mode and choose "with automatic weight"

Comment: Thank you chris.  I ended up doing this and needed to select keep transform in the drop down in the lower left.  This worked!